# Suppose the group satisfies below condition for b!=identity element (e) then what is b^32?

Tags: group-theory

In this one I tried to first pre-multiply by a inverse and then post multiply by a , so I got the equation to be b=b ,Now how to proceed further ?

[image]

Comment: If you do what you say, you should get $a^{-2}ba^2=a^{-1}b^2a$, which does not seem useful.  Maybe you meant to premultiply by $a$ and post multiply by $a^{-1}$, which gives $b=ab^2a^{-1}$

Comment: I am so sorry by mistake the actual expression was http://s27.postimg.org/ua2rradwf/inverse.gif

Comment: Now can u tell what is wrong in my approach ?

Comment: I can't see the link, @radhika.

Comment: http://i.share.pho.to/67477127_c.png

Comment: I have edited the ques ,if link is not accessible

Comment: There's no equation there.

Comment: I am again sorry ,was stucked up with something so uploaded wrong picture , edited now

Comment: There's not much difference, just replace all the $a$ with $a^{-1}$.

Comment: And what about the inverses then ,couldn't get you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated to reflect corrected question(but same idea):  You can multiply together $16$ of your equalities to get $ab^{16}a^{-1}=b^{32}$. I don't know if that is the intended answer.